# Applying a dependency to a service in icinga2

Tags: icinga2

We are using icinga2 for monitoring. We have a lot service checks which are applied dynamically through apply rules.  Additionally, these are services applied to a hashmap of database instances which are on various hosts.  The long and the short of it is that our service names are determined dynamically so one might be, for example `HOST!DBNAME-svcvheck`.

So the scenario is that most of these services depend on a database is up, e.g., `HOST!DBNAME-tnsping".  Unfortunately, the [documentation](https://icinga.com/docs/icinga2/latest/doc/09-object-types/#dependency) examples are fairly simple and don't include dynamically creating a parent service reference.  What I *think* I want to do is something like this:

```
apply Dependency "db-connectivity" to Service {
  parent_service_name = "$host.name$!$service.vars.envname$-tnsping"
  # also tried variants of this, e.g.
  # parent_service_name = host.name + "!" + service.vars.envname + "-tnsping"
  child_service_name = service.name
  child_host_name = host.name
  disable_checks = true
  assign where "oracle-db-svc" in service.templates
}
```

The host doesn't really matter in my case because the dependencies are only the services but the `child_host_name` is a required field.

No matter what I do I can't seem to get it to recognize the parent service.  For example:

```
Error: Dependency 'scan-szepdb041x.myhost.org!UAT2-beqfilelast!db-connectivity' references a parent host/service which doesn't exist.
```

The rules for referencing other object variables while applying a `Dependency` seem a bit different from applying a Service.

Does anyone have any ideas or examples of dynamically apply service dependencies to services which were generated dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

you probably have to loop over existing hosts and see if they match. Then you define dependency inside of a loop.

I had a similar example for dynamically generating disk checks. If i find it, i'll post it here in a few days.

Not sure if that is possible with dependencies, but I'll see.

edit: see if somethig like that will be enough to get you started:

```
for (server in get_objects(Host)) {
        if (match("somename*", server.name)) {
                apply Dependency "db-connectivity" + server.name to Service use (server) {
                        parent_service_name = server.name + service.vars.envvname + "-tnsping"
                        child_service_name = service.name
                        child_host_name = host.name
                        disable_checks = true
                        assign where "oracle-db-svc" in service.templates
                }
        }

}
```